# My app crashes after updating in Android 9(Pie)

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

Yesterday my phone got updated to `Android 9` and by that time my app started crashing. I reinstalled it from the Android Studio, but the problem is still the same. Below is the `Manifest` code to see if there is any problem.
Thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.johny.test">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: @Edward M, Did you check the crash on **Logcat**.

Comment: @RakeshKumar,yes I saw it and I found some errors such us `E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-5` and `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion;`

Comment: I found the solution ,it needs to add `<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />` into AndroidManifest.xml inside the <application> tag.Thank you for your time'

Comment: @EdwardM, Welcome buddy. :)

Answer (score 8):

use this line in your into AndroidManifest.xml inside the `<application>` tag

```
    <application>
       ....
     .... android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

 <uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false" />

    </application>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I solved adding this lines on manifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:name=.....
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    ...
</application>
```

And also creating the network_security_config.xml file on the res/xml folder and then fill it with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">DOMAIN WITHOUT HTTP://</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this line inside the application tag in your manifest file

`<uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false" />`

Comment: With Android 6.0, we removed support for the Apache HTTP client. Beginning with Android 9, that library is removed from the bootclasspath and is not available to apps by default.

for more go to https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28

Comment: You can [edit] your answer to have that info in the right context. Thanks!